# Val Loss and manually calculated loss produce different values

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, tensorflow, cnn, loss-function

I have a CNN classification model that uses loss: binary cross entropy:

```
optimizer_instance = Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate, decay=learning_rate / 200)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer_instance, loss='binary_crossentropy')
```

We are saving the best model so the latest saved model is the one that achieved the best val_loss:

```
es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=0, patience=Config.LearningParameters.Patience)
modelPath = modelFileFolder + Config.LearningParameters.ModelFileName
checkpoint = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(modelPath , monitor='val_loss',
                                                         save_best_only=True,
                                                         save_weights_only=False, verbose=1)
callbacks = [checkpoint,es]
history = model.fit(x=training_generator,
                    batch_size=Config.LearningParameters.Batch_size,
                    epochs=Config.LearningParameters.Epochs,
                    validation_data=validation_generator,                              
                    callbacks=callbacks,
                    verbose=1)
```

on the course of the training the logs show that the val_loss has decreased to 0.41.
At the end of the train we load the best model that was saved during the training process and predicted the validation dataset.
Then we calculated the BCE manually and received a totally different value of 2.335.

here is the manual loss calculation:

```
bce = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy()
binaryCSELoss = bce(y_valid, preds)
print("Calculated Val Loss is: " + str(binaryCSELoss ))
```

here is the end of the  training logs:

```
10/10 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0778
Epoch 40: val_loss did not improve from 0.41081
10/10 [==============================] - 4s 399ms/step - loss: 0.0778 - val_loss: 0.5413
% of marked 1 in validation: [0.51580906 0.48419094]
% of marked 1 in Test: [0.51991504 0.480085  ]
---------------------------------
Calculated Val Loss is: 2.3350689765791395
```

We thought that it might have to do something with the face that we are using data generators and the loss is then calculated on the batches individually so we added another test where we do not use data generators:

```
history = model.fit(x=trainX,y = y_train,
                      epochs=Config.LearningParameters.Epochs,
                      validation_data=(validateion_x,y_valid),
                      callbacks=callbacks,
                      verbose=1)
predictions_cnn = model.predict(validateion_x)
bce = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=False)
binaryCSELoss = bce(y_valid, predictions_cnn)
valloss = binaryCSELoss.numpy()
print("binaryCSELoss logits=false on all Val Loss is: " + str(valloss))
bce = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
binaryCSELoss = bce(y_valid, predictions_cnn)
valloss = binaryCSELoss.numpy()
print("binaryCSELoss logits=true on all Val Loss is: " + str(valloss))
```

Here is the end of the training log. Again the loss is no the same:

```
54/54 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.5015
Epoch 6: val_loss did not improve from 0.66096
54/54 [==============================] - 8s 144ms/step - loss: 0.5015 - val_loss: 1.9742
% of marked 1 in validation: [0.28723404 0.71276593]
% of marked 1 in Test: [0.52077866 0.47922137]
loading Model: E:\CnnModels\2022-06-03_11-53-53\model.h5
Backend TkAgg is interactive backend. Turning interactive mode on.
binaryCSELoss logits=false on all Val Loss is: 0.6353029
binaryCSELoss logits=true on all Val Loss is: 0.7070135
```

How can this be?

Comment: What code are you using to calculate the validation loss yourself?

Comment: @Oxbowerce added to the question

Comment: It might have to do with a difference in how the losses are calculated over the samples (i.e. all samples or only the samples in a batch). I am not sure how many batches you have or what your batch size is, but the value for `val_loss` seems to be the average batch loss, whereas the loss you calculate yourself is the loss over all samples in your validation dataset.

Comment: @Oxbowerce I actually thought about that just now. my batch size is 16 and I am using a DataGenerator so it makes sense that the loss is calculated per batch. I tried splitting the results into batches of 16, calculating the loss on each batch and then averaging but still its not the same. the val_loss is 0.76 and I get 0.71 so its still weird.

Comment: @Oxbowerce I tested it with no data generator and still got different losses. I have updated the question